# How to get a link to go to a specific div on another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink, anchor

Say I have a link that says:

`<a href="services">Services</a>`

When I click on that link I want to obviously go to the services page, but what I am trying to figure out is how can I get that link to take me to a specific section on that page.

The thing is, the page I want to show a specific section, it does not show unless I hit a tab. Here is what my services page looks like. You will see if you click a tab a specific section will show up.

https://jsfiddle.net/esayoaqg/1/

If I clicked on a link referring to Service 1, I want the link to go to the services page and show the div `#service1`.

How can I do this?

```
<a href="serviceCheck1#service1">Service 1</a>
<a href="serviceCheck1#service2">Service 2</a>
<a href="serviceCheck1#service3">Service 3</a>

$(function(){

    //get the section name from hash
    var sectionName = window.location.hash.slice(1);

    //then show the section
    $('#service-display-box').show();
    //$('#' + sectionName ).show();
    $('#service' + sectionName).show().siblings().hide();
})
```

Comment: To whoever says this question is already answered CLEARLY did not read this fully. The section I want to show is not visible and requires clicking a button to show it.

Answer (score 4):

you could use hash sign `#`:

```
<a href="services#service1">Services</a>

//services.html   
<div id="service1">...</div>
```

UPDATED:

if you need to auto show a section after page loaded, you could do something like:

```
$(function(){

    //get the section name from hash
    var sectionName = window.location.hash.slice(1);

    //then show the section
    $('#' + sectionName ).show();
})
```

Comment: Will this show that div since it is hidden? You will also see in my fiddle that I show the `#service-display-box` as well when someone clicks on the buttons up top. Is there anyway to show that from a link?

Comment: please see my updates to show how to auto show hidden div after page loaded

Comment: Could I change this per section I have or will it only work to autoshow one section? I will always need to autoshow the `service-display-box`, however the section inside of that will differ per link clicked. ie: When service1 link is clicked the service1 section needs to show and so on.

Comment: I updated my question with what I tried. I am getting the `service-display-box` to show, but all of the other services are still showing. I only want to show the service selected.

Comment: For the update, you could do something like that where?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<a href="blah.html#gohere">blah blah</a>

<p id="gohere">show this content</p>
```

and then use a show content based on scroll or window location..

Most likely will need javascript of the sorts to get it how you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an anchor, but it will not set the hidden element to visible.

You'll need to add some javascript to display it. 
Based on the example in your fiddle, it would be as follows:

```
var index = location.hash.indexOf('#service');
if(index > -1) {
    var serviceId = parseInt(location.hash.substring(index));
    if(serviceId) {
        $('#service-display-box').show();
        $('#service' + serviceId).show().siblings().hide();
    }
}
```